# How do I get gpg to generate a GPG Key public ring rather than a keybox?

Tags: gnupg, apt

I'm trying to take a public key and add it to `/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/`, but I'm getting an incompatibility issue.

I run:

`gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/example.gpg --import file.asc`

Which works.

But then when I use `apt-key list` it says the key is incompatible.

Looking at the file types, my `example.gpg` is of type `GPG keybox database version 1`, where as the other apt keys are of type `GPG key public ring`.

How do I get `gpg` to generate a `GPG key public ring` rather than a `keybox`?

Comment: Note that [`apt-key` is deprecated](https://manpages.debian.org/testing/apt/apt-key.8.en.html)

Answer (score 7):

I know that this is old, but since I spent some time finding a solution, I am going to share it.

GnuPG has always been a pain, when it comes to automation and there doesn't seem to be a way, to make it use the old keyring v4 format.
However it can be done by re-exporting the key. Here an ugly one-liner with the MariaDB repo as an example:

```
# cd /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ && wget -q -O - https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc | \
  gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=$(pwd)/mariadb.gpg --batch --import - && \
  gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring=$(pwd)/mariadb.gpg --batch --output $(pwd)/mariadb.gpg~ --export --yes && \
  mv $(pwd)/mariadb.gpg~ $(pwd)/mariadb.gpg; chmod 644 $(pwd)/mariadb.gpg
```

This can be done much easier with `apt-key` and its `--keyring` option (tested on Debian Buster 10.7).

```
$ wget -q -O - https://mariadb.org/mariadb_release_signing_key.asc | \
  sudo apt-key --keyring /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/mariadb.gpg add -
```

If you look at the `apt-key` script you will find something similar to the one-liner above (but probably more robust).
Note that `apt-key` will complain and fail, if you use the suffix `.asc` instead of `.gpg` for the trusted file. That seems to be a bug, that can be avoided with a previous `touch` on the file.

Answer (score 7):

I also recently stumbled across this issue, and after digging into the source code, I found pretty much the perfect solution.

You can just specify the keyring format with a prefix, so `gnupg-ring:` or `gnupg-kbx:`. In your case, the command would be:

`gpg --no-default-keyring --keyring gnupg-ring:/etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/example.gpg --import file.asc`